# angular ui sortable doesn't work with preloaded table rows

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a html table in which i'm trying to add the ui-sortable directive for being able to sort the rows by drag and drop. I will explain a little about my project so this question is understandable. I have a html file that works for differents pages in my site, and each page has its own controller. When I get to the page in which the table has no elements (its the page where i 'create fields'), i add some rows to the table and i can succesfully drag and drop them to change the order. But when i'm in the page where i can edit a table that has been previously saved, and the table is loaded from a data base (using webservices), the rows are loaded correctly and i can drag them, but when i drop them in other place, they return to their previous location (meaning: i can't change the order of the rows, i can simply drag them but with no effect). I've been searching for a while but i didn't find anything useful to help me with this, and to be honest i don't know how to keep doing it for this particular problem.

HTML:

```
<tbody ng-model="campos" ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ui-sortable-stop="actualizarPosicion()">
        <tr ng-repeat="campo in camposConfigurados() track by $index" class="sortable-item">
            <td class="text-center">{{campo.Nombre}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{campo.FormatoDato.Formato}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{campo.Posicion}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{campo.Longitud}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="campo.LongitudFija ? 'glyphicon-check' : 'glyphicon-unchecked'"></span>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="campo.CompletarConCeros ? 'glyphicon-check' : 'glyphicon-unchecked'"></span>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" uib-tooltip="Editar" tooltip-placement="top" ng-click="editarCampo(campo)">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" uib-tooltip="Ver Traductores" tooltip-placement="top" ng-disabled="campo.Traductores.length == 0" ng-click="mostrarModalTraductores(campo)">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" uib-tooltip="Eliminar" tooltip-placement="top" ng-click="eliminarCampo(campo)">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

JS:

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
        cursor: "move",
        'ui-floating': false,
        helper: function(event, ui) {
            ui.children().each(function() {
                $(this).width($(this).width());
            });
            return ui;
        },
    }

    $scope.camposConfigurados = function() {
        return $scope.camposCuerpo;
    }

    $scope.campos = $scope.camposConfigurados();

    $scope.actualizarPosicion = function() {
        $scope.camposConfigurados().forEach(function(campo) {
            campo.Posicion = $scope.camposConfigurados().indexOf(campo) + 1;
        }, this);
    }
```

As you can see, in the controller i have a var named camposCuerpo, and in the html i call it through the camposConfigurados() method. This is because the html is used by several controllers, and each one of them has their own 'campos' (camposCuerpo, camposPie, camposEncabezado...).
I've read in some sites that the ng-model from the table body and the ng-repeat should be the same, something like this:

```
 <tbody ng-model="campos" ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ui-sortable-stop="actualizarPosicion()">
        <tr ng-repeat="campo in campos track by $index" class="sortable-item">
```

I tried this, that's why i have this line $scope.campos = $scope.camposConfigurados();
But when i do this, the campos variable is not loaded correctly, if i log it in the console, it shows as undefined.